# Put a Thread to sleep but keep animations going - is this possible?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uisearchdisplaycontroller

This might be a strange question but there might be a different solution for what I'm trying to achieve, I'm open to anything that works as needed!

Facts:

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` handled by a `UISearchDisplayController`.

Above said TableView I have some buttons and a small `UIScrollView`.

When the user taps the SearchBar and the keyboard comes up, there is very little space to show the search results while typing.

Therefore I want to move the TableView all the way to the top (covering the buttons and the ScrollView) when the user begins a search.

My code and the problem:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
...

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Search" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
[self.attractionsTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

...
return;
```

}

Now the problem is that since the distance my `UITableView` has to travel is about 100 points, the SearchDisplayController is faster with putting the black overlay on top of the TableView and thus the black overlay is already on top while the TableView is still sliding up there.

The result is a screen that looks kinda like this:

[problem http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/9186/problemqdu.png](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/9186/problemqdu.png)

So the user sees the TableView sliding up (which would be fine) but the black overlay is already up there waiting because the searchDisplayController's animation is faster than mine.

So I have a possible idea but don't know how to do this:

Is there a way to set the duration of the animation of the searchDisplayController putting the black overlay on top of the search tableView?

EDIT:

I know I can set the animationDuration to 0.01 or even 0, but the speed of 0.6 seems pretty ok for a distance of 100 points, so I'm trying to find a different solution that lowering the duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is not let the run loop run normally until your animation is done. Animations are performed when the run loop is running in a certain mode. Luckily, the overlay animation is performed in a different run loop mode than other animations, which run in the default run loop mode. So, all you have to do is run the run loop from within your method until the animation is complete.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    BOOL done = NO;
    // Pass the done variable's address as the context so we can be notified
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"SearchExpand" context:&done];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone:finished:context:)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    // Expend the table view to fill its superview
    self.attractionsTableView.frame = [[self.attractionsTableView superview] bounds];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    // Run the run loop until the animation completes
    while(!done) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        if(![runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]])
            break;
        [pool drain];
    }
}

- (void)animationDone:(NSString *)name finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    // Set the done flag to YES
    *((BOOL*)context) = YES;
    // and kill the run loop
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! amazing! :) you're the man!

One question though: what is the (NSNumber *)finished argument for in the (void)animationDone method?

Comment: Another question: Is there any documentation about this? Because I kind of understood it, but I don't think I could use this in any other context. And is there a way to find out whether an animation is performed in this "different run loop mode"?

Comment: Third question (sorry).. I don't understand why we create a new NSAutoreleasePool in the while loop. I just tried commenting it out to maybe find an exception that would help me understand what it's for, but it still works without the pool. Is this bad code or have I created a memory leak or something?

Comment: @Octoshape The `finished` argument will contain `YES` if the animation finished, and `NO` if it was stopped. The animation running in a different mode is not documented. I found out by trial and error. The autorelease pool is basically a safety measure, since you don't know what will happen in the run loop. There could be a significant amount of autoreleased memory generated.

Comment: This is absolutely the BEST work-around I've ever seen for a UI issue! :) Kudos for "giving a damn". :)